# Silent Renew using oidc-client in case SameSite=Lax

Tags: identityserver4, oidc-client-js, samesite

Chrome plans to implement the new secure-by-default model for cookies with Chrome 80 in February 2020. 
Now I am testing all our applications that might be affected.

For authentication/authorization we use oidc-client (on UI) and IndentityServer on backend.

The workflow is the following:

**request**:

POST http://my_identity_server/api/authenticate 
{userName, password}

**response**:

Set-Cookie: idsrv=abc

{"redirectUrl":"http://my_identity_server/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=MyApplication&response_type=id_token token&scope=openid"}

**request**

http://my_identity_server/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=MyApplication&response_type=id_token token&scope=openid"
Cookie: idsrv=abc

**response**:

302 Location: http://myApplication/#id_token=123&access_token=456&token_type=Bearer

**request**

http://myApplication/#id_token=123&access_token=456&token_type=Bearer

When application is loaded, Oidc-client adds IFrame to do silentRenew that actually **sends additional requests**

GET http://my_identity_server/connect/authorize?client_id=MyApplication&response_type=id_token token&prompt=none
Cookie: idsrv=abc

What I don't understand **why this last requests indide IFrame include idsrv cookie?** The request is done inside an IFrame and it's definitely a third-party cookie.
If I switch SameSite setting to "Strict" everything works as expected, cookies are not send.

If someone can explain me the case or suggest some ideas to check, would be nice! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

OIDC client library uses OIDC session management to track of the session which is done by using OP iframe and client(RP) iframe.

Identity server issues idsrv:session cookie for this purpose

check this
https://medium.com/@piraveenaparalogarajah/openid-connect-session-management-dc6a65040cc